# Database design for a wedding photography booking system website

Tags: database, database-design, schema, relational-database, database-schema

I'm really stuck on the best way to implement this database.

Here is my problem: The database is to store information on wedding photography clients.

- A user can sign up to my site, enter the details of their wedding and get their own "wedding profile page". They can do this without having to have us shoot their wedding.
- At any point the user can book a meetup, wedding, or engagement shoot. The website will check if we are available. (weddings take preference over meetups so a client that wants to book a wedding on a day we have a meetup, the meetup will be flagged for a reschedule)
- We must also be able to book days off. On these days a wedding/meetup/engagement shoot can not be booked.
- engagement shoots cost and upfront fee. With weddings, a deposit is due within 14 days or the date is freed up again. Meetups are free.

I am so stuck with how to implement this system. I just keep going round in circles, the best way I can think is to have a "dates" table, that links all the other tables but I'm sure this is not the most efficient way.

I think what is putting me off is the fact that there can be multiple weddings on the same day (for people who just want a wedding profile), but only one BOOKED wedding per day.

[image: Tables Preview]

So have I got this completely wrong? or do I store all appointments in one table and use a "type of appointment" table.

SO SO Stuck, I hope you can help me!

P.S. I have missed most fields out to make it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple to begin with. You've identified many of the nouns that should correspond to entities:

USERS
WEDDINGS
ENGAGEMENT_SHOOTS
MEETUPS
UNAVAILABLE
DATES
PAYMENTS

I'd suggest that WEDDINGS, ENGAGEMENT_SHOOTS, MEETUPS and UNAVAILABLE are all type of bookings. You could have just:

USERS
BOOKINGS - this has a date and perhaps a status
BOOKING_TYPE (wedding, meetup, engagement_shoots, unavailable)
PAYMENTS

You may wish to package up all on the things a use has bought relating to a single wedding into a TRANSACTION entity etc which will allow a single payment to be mapped to multiple bookings. When one of your staff isn't available they could have a booking of type holiday etc.

There may be 2 types of USERS - your photography staff who are assigned to a booking and your customer.

Based on the status of the booking, eg. CONFIRMED, PENDING, COMPLETED and the date your business logic could send out payment demands, followups etc.

Create a simple model and start adding data you will soon see the gaps and issues if any. You should have test cases up front to ensure that the data model supports all the scenarios for your application, best to do this with a set of use cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, it's greatly appreciated. I thought about doing it this way. But when I tried to design it I ran into a few problems. Mainly, for a wedding I need to store a different set of data. For example, information for a wedding will include locations, guest lists, accommodation recommendations, gift suggestions, a history of the couple etc. So i'm guessing this would have to be stored in a different table and linked somehow?

Comment: The datamodel is just there to store your data efficiently and make the application easy to develop and support. It would be perfectly possible to assume that a customer will always have one or more consultations, one or more engagement shoots and at least one wedding and hang all of the information off the wedding. This would potentially make it more difficult if you decided you wanted to branch out into other types of business in the future. If the wedding has so much extra data associated with it there is no reason why it couldn't have it's own entity.

Comment: Don't overthink it to begin with and try to throw something together. Read about normal forms and use them as guidelines, not the law. Consider what input screens and reports will look like and see if they will be possible/easy to implement with the structure you have